# ORA-40478: output value too large (maximum: 4000) while using JSON_ARRAYAGG

Tags: python, json, oracle, python-oracledb

I am trying to get output of a query from a oracle database as JSON, through JSON_ARRAYAGG.

```
#   SELECT name AS name FROM admin_users
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(name) AS name FROM admin_users
```

However, above gives me:

```
ORA-40478: output value too large (maximum: 4000)
```

Using `RETURNING CLOB` resolves the issue but it returns `(<oracledb.LOB object at 0x0000021F5DA12C10>,)` instead of JSON.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(name RETURNING CLOB) AS name FROM admin_users
```

Is there a way to fix the output value error without changing the return type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON_ARRAYAGG` will default to returning a `VARCHAR2` and `VARCHAR2` is limited to 4000 characters so you either:

1. Return a `VARCHAR2` and if the output is over 4000 characters then you will get an exception; or
2. Use `RETURNING CLOB` which will allow you to have more than 4000 characters and then you read the value from the `CLOB` using:

   - [`clob_variable.read()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html) or
   - Set [`oracledb.defaults.fetch_lobs = False`](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes) so that "CLOBs and BLOBs smaller than 1 GB can queried from the database directly as strings and bytes."

As pointed out by [@ChristopherJones in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76666054/ora-40478-output-value-too-large-maximum-4000-while-using-json-arrayagg/76668142?noredirect=1#comment135181334_76668142), there is [a JSON example in the documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/json_data_type.html#accessing-relational-data-as-json).

Comment: Use RETURNING CLOB but follow [this cx_Oracle doc](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes) so that you don't have to call `c.read()` which is slow. With the latest cx_Oracle (now called python-oracledb), there is a one-liner to get the performance benefits, see the [doc](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes).  A JSON example is in the doc [here](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/json_data_type.html#accessing-relational-data-as-json).

Comment: @ChristopherJones I've update the answer with your comments.